# Write json to syslog using docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, syslog, stdio

I am looking at docker-compose and trying to configure it to write to syslog:
https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/

but I want to write JSON to syslog if possible, does anyone know if that can configured? alternatively, if I use `json-file` for the logging, how do I capture those logs? To capture the `syslog` logs, I just need to do:

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

but how would I capture the logs if json-file is used?

Answer (score 0):

To use syslog:

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#logging

For read logs from the docker-compose, use:

```
docker-compose logs --help
```